# ABOUT text.box empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

after inserting,updating and deleting i want my TEXT.BOX empty...so how can i do it....????

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //delete
{
    if (TexBo_num.Text == "")
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('contact_no is coumpulsary');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SYSTEM2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=amresh;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from detail where contact_no=" + TexBo_num.Text, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('record deleted')", true);
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, just set it's Text property after you executed the comman.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
TexBo_num.Text = "";
```

Note that you should use sql-parameters to [prevent sql-injection attacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx).

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from detail where contact_no=@contactNo", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactNo", TexBo_num.Text);
```